# Associate radio buttons with table rows in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am making a website using django.  I have a pandas dataframe that I've converted to an html table in my `views.py` using pandas `DataFrame.to_html()`. I want to be able to add a radio button to each row of the table so that the user can select which row of the dataframe they want to use for further processing.  I have a radio button form in django but am not sure how to apply it to the table.

form looks like this:

```
class RadioSelectForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    arg_list = kwargs.pop('arg_list')
    section_label = kwargs.pop('section_label')
    required_val = kwargs.pop('required_val')

    super(RadioSelectForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['choice'].choices = arg_list
    self.fields['choice'].label = section_label
    self.fields['choice'].required = required_val

  choice = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

html template looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
  <div class="panel-title text-center">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      {{ table1 | safe }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

views.py table generation looks like this (would like to add radio buttons to each row in this table):

```
dumy_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))  #just a placeholder dataframe for this question
html_df = dumy_df.to_html(classes="table table-hover")
template_dict = {'table1':html_df}

return render(request,'DjangoTemplateName.html',template_dict)
```

Does anyone know if you can associate radio buttons with rows in a table in Django?

Comment: How are you constructing the table? It would be helpful to see the html.

Comment: @onyeka see edits to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has an [insert](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) function you can use to add a column to the generated table. I don't know what you're using to id your individual rows, but let's say we use the values in column A, you can run through the rows.

```
radio = [] # empty array to push the rows of input tags 
for val in dumy_df.['A']:
    radio.append('<input type="radio" value="{}">'.format(val))
```

So you could try `dumy_df.insert(0, 'E', radio , allow_duplicates=True)`

0, being the location, radio being html for the radio button like

Then you could wrap the whole table in a form tag.

```
<form action="/some_link/" method="post">
  <div class="table-responsive">
     {{ table1 | safe }}
   </div>
</form>
```

I haven't tried this in entirety, but something along these lines might work.

**Edit2**: Okay, see above.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was struggling with.  I was able to put radio buttons in a empty column at the end of the table but they weren't really associated with any data.

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't know what you use to id each row or the content of your table. But assuming there's a column called 'ID' you can work with something like that. Let me know if the above helps/works.

Comment: Neat approach. Tried and failed to get it to work appropriately (it looked like a new column with HTML code within it when it rendered). If you did get it to work, would love a full answer.